# Google Tag Manager and data layer

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

I want to track an image which directs to a URL. I have installed the code snippet of Tag manager.

Do i need some other code to initialize the Data layer or it is not essential? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dataLayer is automatically created with the GTM object. You can verify this by inspecting the dataLayer either in the console or in GTM debug mode. You should see events in there like gtm.js and gtm.dom and gtm.load.

Comment: Do I need to initialize the dataLayer in order to track an image? I do not think that is essential. Could you answer me please?

Comment: No, you don't need to initialize the dataLayer.